# Matlab: evaluate a symbolic function with vector and matrix arguments

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, vector

I want to do something like this:

```
syms x1 x2 h11 h12 h21 h22
x = [x1 x2]
matrix = [h11 h12; h21 h22]
```

And then create my function as:

```
f(x, matrix) = ((2*matrix)^(-1/2))*(x');
```

But I must be doing something wrong because I get:

> Error using sym/cat>checkDimensions (line 75) CAT arguments dimensions
>   are not consistent.
>
> Error in sym/cat>catMany (line 38) [resz, ranges] =
>   checkDimensions(sz,dim);
>
> Error in sym/cat (line 27)
>       ySym = catMany(dim, strs);
>
> Error in sym/horzcat (line 19)
>       ySym = cat(2,args{:});
>
> Error in sym/subsasgn (line 1639)
>                   C = symfun(B,[inds{:}]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your function definition. See this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html) for how to correctly declare a function in MATLAB.

Put this in a separate file named "your_function_name.m"

```
function result = your_function_name(x, matrix)
result = ((2*matrix)^(-1/2))*(x');
```

Then you can call your function like this:

```
x = [x1 x2];
matrix = [h11 h12; h21 h22];
your_function_name(x, matrix);
```

Or you can use an [anonymous](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?s_tid=doc_12b) function.

```
x = [x1 x2];
matrix = [h11 h12; h21 h22];
f = @(x, m) ((2*m)^(-1/2))*(x');
f(x, matrix);
```